# Docker Desktop for Windows - does not start because of Bitlocker

Tags: windows, docker, bitlocker

since 2 days I cannot start Docker Desktop for Windows anymore. It says "Current Operation failed because Windows policy "Deny write access to fixed drives not protected by Bitlocker" is enabled. Please disable it and retry the Operation". I already changed the policy entry (exactly this one) in the registry and restarted the computer. Without effect. One reason could be that I deactivated Hyper-V because I needed to run Oracle Virtual Box. Hyper-V is activated again. But it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. The issue arises only if switch to Windows Containers. So nothing has changed on my computer ("since 2 days"). I just had Linux turned on.

To fix the problem:

•   Turn off Bitlocker before installation: control panel > System Security > Bitlocker Drive Encryption > Turn off Bitlocker (in most companies, this is not possible).

•   Install Docker for Windows for Linux Containers.

•   Change registry: Local Machine > System > Current Control Set > Policies > Microsoft > FVE > FDVFenyWriteAccess > ValueData: 0 > restart Windows.

•   If it does not help: gpedit.msc (Group Policy Editor) > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > BitLocker Drive Encryption > Fixed Data Drives > Deny write access to fixed drives not protected by BitLocker > Disabled > restart Windows